# Linear equations with modulo

Tags: python, linear-algebra

This is what I am actually trying to do

Example:

```
>>> x = matrix([[5,1],[2,4]])
>>> y = matrix([[1,5],[3,3]])
>>> print x
[[5 1]
 [2 4]]
>>> print y
[[1 5]
 [3 3]]
>>> print x*y % 7
[[1 0]
 [0 1]]
```

Now, in this supposing I don't know `y`.

I can calculate it using linear equations, like these:

```
5a + c = 1 mod7
5b + d = 0 mod7
2a + 4c = 0 mod7
2b + 4d = 1 mod7
```

Without the `mod7`, I can do it like this:

```
a = np.array([[5,0,1,0],[0,5,0,1],[2,0,4,0],[0,2,0,4]])
b = np.array([[1,0,1,0]])
x = np.linalg.solve(a,b)
```

But how do I do it with `mod7`?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = y mod7
```

is equal to

```
x = 7k + y
```

So, your original linear system

```
5a      +  c      = 1 mod7
   + 5b      +  d = 0 mod7
2a      + 4c      = 1 mod7
2b           + 4d = 0 mod7
```

is equal to

```
5a      +  c      - 7e = 1
   + 5b      +  d - 7f = 0
2a      + 4c      - 7g = 1
2b           + 4d - 7h = 0
```

As you can see, you have four equations for eight unknowns. So you won’t have a unique solution.